# How to extract links from the first search results?

Tags: web-scraping, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm using Power Automate Desktop. What I need to achieve is an automated extraction of links that works as described below:

1. In Excel, content of A2 cell is copied.
2. It's pasted into Google search engine.
3. URL of the first search result is extracted.
4. The extracted URL is pasted into cell B2.
5. The process is looped and repeated for all cells in column A.

I managed to create the whole flow, but the problem lays in step 3. I can't find a way for the tool to always copy the first URL that pops up, doesn't matter what's the content of cells in column A.

I tried using two options:

1. **"Get details of element on webpage"**. By using this option, I managed to extract the URL for the one specific term that's in the cell A2 right now. But when I change the content of this cell, and therefore the search results change, it's an error.
2. **"Extract data from webpage"**. With this one I have a problem with live web helper and selecting href element. It's as if it doesn't read the element I indicate.

What I expect is a universal way for getting URLs, no matter what terms are present in column A.

I will be very grateful for some support!

Alex

Comment: tried https://exceljet.net/functions/filterxml-function ? pls share us some insight if its fruitful/not.